# Client could not run .NET app, has right version..advice please

Tags: c#, deployment

I have created and deployed simple DB app and sent it to my client (the whole directory that Publish generates). On my PC it is OK but he gets messages like " sqlceme35.dll" is missing (SQL Ce). He does have 3.5 version of .NET. In the publish options, prerequisities, there is SQL CE and .NET 3.5 SP1 checked. Please could you advice me?

UPDATE: Now I can see there is a problem with path to local DB, is it correct to have its Build action to "content"?
Thank you!

Comment: Is this a Windows Mobile App?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you copy 'sqlceme35.dll' to your bin folder it should work.

See this blog for more information: http://blogs.msdn.com/sqlservercompact/archive/2007/10/26/can-t-find-p-invoke-dll-sqlcemenn-dll.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't using CE ME, remove the prerequisite and reference?  Shouldn't be needed unless it's a mobile app.